# Using codeceptJS with PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, editor, phpstorm, webstorm, codeceptjs

I'm just starting with [codeceptJS](http://codecept.io/) and I'd like the PhpStorm editor to recognize the code correctly.

I have tried telling the editor to Use JavaScript Library with Node.js Core and Globals. I've searched plugins for one that would help and the web. Nothing...

I can just start disabling inspections but I would like to have all the nice editor features functional.

I am using PhpStorm 8 but can upgrade if it helps.

Anyone know how to setup PhpStorm so it handles codeceptJS code correctly?

Comment: Definitely try latest stable version (10.0.3 I believe) -- you can run them in parallel (settings are stored in separate places) -- just keep copy of `.idea` subfolder (your project settings) as every new version brings some changes to them (use backup if you decide to go back to v8). On another hand -- I do not see any mentions of codeceptJS in any tickets (in case if it needs any special support from code point of view) -- feel free to file new one if such support is needed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to make PhpStorm "happy" with codeceptJS code. In JavaScript settings set the language version to ECMAScript 6 and check Prefer Strict mode.

Now inspections and code reformat works correctly.